# Autosize Image in Picture Box

Tags: c#, image

I'm doing an imageviewer. I've already done importing the image in the picture box.

Which code should be used to autosize the image in the picture box? Here's my code in Viewing the image in picture box.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg|Bitmaps|*.bmp";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pFileNames = openFileDialog.FileNames;
            pCurrentImage = 0;
            ImageView();
        }
    }

    protected void ImageView()
    {
        if (pCurrentImage >= 0 && pCurrentImage <= pFileNames.Length - 1)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(pFileNames[pCurrentImage]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you want to autosize the image itself, or the picturebox?

Comment: I think it is picturbox1.SizeMode = SizeMode.Zoom. You will find it in the properties of  the picturebox.

Comment: just use the SizeMode property and set it to AutoSize and I think you should be fine. [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) in case you need more help on the subject.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the `SizeMode` property of the `PictureBox`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx

Set this to `AutoSize` and you're ready to go.

[Check here what you can set it to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Check [PictureBox.SizeMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) and set it by [PictureBoxSizeMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx) as you want PictureBox control to do while displaying the image.

- AutoSize means that the PictureBox is going to fit to the image.

If you want image fit to the pictureBox then set the sizemode to *StretchImage*

```
// Set the SizeMode property to the StretchImage value.  
// This will enlarge the image as needed to fit into 
// the PictureBox.
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the SizeMode property on the PictureBox to AutoSize.